# Scale up image until either height or width is 100%

Tags: html, css

I have an image element, it can contain any aspect ratio of the image (eg horizontal and vertical). I want to fill the page with it until either its height or width is 100% of the page.

I tried checking the image height and width and setting min-width/height to 100%. This worked very well for vertical images, but with horizontal images, sometimes the 100% height gets reached before the width does, (especially on 4:3 aspect ratio images).

Basically, I just want it to fill either the height or width of the screen, depending on what happens first.

Comment: Use `object-fit: fill` on the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `object-fit` property will do this if you set it to contain (if you set it to fill it will become distorted if the aspect ratio of the container and the img are not the same).

Here's a simple example, change the viewport dimensions to see the affect on the image:

```css
.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: gray;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/768/1024"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried object-fit with almost all values, however i did not specifically set the height and width to 100% before using object-fit. Which made it have no effect no matter what i did.

Answer (score 2):

Try with object-fit on image, so it fits it's container and chose the value that suits your needs best.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: I tried this with almost all values, however i did not specifically set the height and width to 100% before using object-fit. Which made it have no effect no matter what i did.